# Cannot parse threeten datetime to a specific format

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to format Threeten datetime, from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Below is the code, I'm using to achieve the task.

```
public void testChangeFormat() {
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-10T15:14:05", inputFormatter);
    System.out.println(date1); // prints 2020-03-10T15:14:05
    String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date1);
    System.out.println(formattedDate); // prints 2020-03-10 15:14:05
    LocalDateTime newFormattedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate);
    System.out.println(newFormattedDateTime);
}
```

Everything seems to work as expected until I try to parse the `formattedDate` to LocalDateTime, at `LocalDateTime newFormattedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate);`

I even get the datetime formatted as `2020-03-10 15:14:05` using `outputFormatter`, but when I try to parse that to LocalDateTime, it gives me the following exception:

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-03-10 15:14:05' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is a date/time *value*, it doesn't have a format. If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--), you will see that it always renders the date/time value using the `T` separator. If you want the date/time value in a different format, use the [`format(DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) method.

Comment: Same for the [`parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) method. It can only parse strings with the `T` separator. If you want to parse a text in a different format, use the [`parse(String, DateTimeFormatter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) method.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate)` are using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` (that is format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`). That's why you get the exception when trying to parse string that has format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. You should use:

`LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate, outputFormatter)` if you wnat to do the parse to `LocalDateTime` again for some reason.

Note:
You have the printed format you at line: `outputFormatter.format(date1)` right?

Comment: using `LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate, outputFormatter)` gives me the datetime like `2020-03-10T15:14:05`

Comment: What do you wnat exactly? you have the format you want on this line `outputFormatter.format(date1)` right?

Comment: `outputFormatter.format(date1)` has the datetime format I want in String, and I want to parse that to actual DateTime.

Comment: That you have already on your 3rd line `LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-10T15:14:05", inputFormatter);` or do you want it to a `ZonedDateTime` or what? (LocalDateTime is a DateTime in the current timezone)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused between `LocalDateTime` and format (which is a string representation).

A `LocalDateTime` always has `T` in it when you print its object using `System.out.println` (which implicitly calls `toString` as you most likely already know)  e.g.

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
```

will output `2020-04-14T09:36:04.723994`.

See below how the `toString` of `LocalDateTime` has been implemented:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return date.toString() + 'T' + time.toString();
}
```

and therefore your following statement will always show `'T'` in it:

```
System.out.println(newFormattedDateTime);
```

It's up to you to format a `LocalDateTime` into the `String` representation of your choice. As I have mentioned in the first line, formats are strings i.e. you format a `LocalDateTime` into a `String` representation where you can apply all the options provided by `DateTimeFormatter`.

The correct way of converting the `formattedDate` to `LocalDateTime` is by applying the corresponding format which is specified in `outputFormatter`.

```
LocalDateTime newFormattedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(formattedDate,outputFormatter);
```

How date and time are stored in a `LocalDateTime` object shouldn't be a concern. We can always create the string in the required format from it.