# Java 8 LocalDateTime

Tags: datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java-time

I have a simple Java LocalDateTime like below:

```
    DateTimeFormatter theDtFrmtr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy h:mm a");
    String strDate = "3/23/21 1:17 PM";
    LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, theDtFrmtr);
    System.out.println("localDate - "+ localDate);
```

It results in: `localDate - 2021-03-23T13:17`

I am expecting it to be is - `localDate - 2021-03-23 1:17 pm`

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you print a date, its `toString()` is called, and that prints hours in 24h format. The only way to get the output in the format you want is to use that formatter. So print with `System.out.println("localDate - "+ theDtFrmtr.format(localDate));`. A `LocalDateTime` object does not carry intrinsic formats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can’t rid of 'T' in LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311884/can-t-rid-of-t-in-localdatetime). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54941872/parsing-timestamp-as-localdatetime) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203388/cannot-parse-threeten-datetime-to-a-specific-format)?

Comment: No Ole. It was just the issued about printing the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JAVA Oracle docs,

- `static LocalDateTime parse(CharSequence text)`
  Obtains an instance of LocalDateTime from a text string such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.
- `static LocalDateTime parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)`
  Obtains an instance of LocalDateTime from a text string using a specific formatter.

DateTimeFormatter object needs to be formatted.